# Is there a way to check if an object is a table or a view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that I am changing to a table in SQL Server.

I am dropping the view and then the next part of my code I am establishing the table.

My code works the first time I run it (when the object is a view), but when I need to run it multiple times, I get this error:

> Cannot use DROP VIEW with 'engineer.Well' because 'engineer.Well' is a table. Use DROP TABLE.

I've been looking online but cannot find a way to check if an object is a table or a view, and the subsequently drop the object.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Right now it looks like this,

```
IF OBJECT_ID('engineer.well') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [engineer].[Well]
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED TABLE Vendor >>>'
END
```

I am playing around with a way to check if the object is a table and then drop it, or check if it is a view then drop it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the system views.

```
DECLARE @Type varchar(2)
SELECT @Type = type 
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE o.name = 'well'
AND s.name = 'engineer'

IF  @Type = 'U'
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [engineer].[Well]
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED TABLE Vendor >>>'
END

IF  @Type = 'V'
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW [engineer].[Well]
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED VIEW Vendor >>>'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('name'), 'IsView') 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
or 
SELECT id, type FROM sysobjects where id=OBJECT_ID('objectName')

Answer (score 0):

You can query sys.objects table:

```
select type_desc, * from sys.objects where object_id = object_id('[dbo].[DimDates]')
```